# Meteor subscribe callback running when subscription contains previous subscribe result

Tags: javascript, angular, meteor, callback

I am fairly new to meteor, and I am running into a strange issue with subscribe callbacks. I have a database containing courses and reviews. I'm using a publish/subscribe model on the reviews to return reviews that are only relevant to a selected class, and I want this to change each time a new class is clicked on. I want to print all the reviews and compile some metrics about the reviews (average quality, difficulty rating). Using the following code, with a subscribe that updates the reviews sent to the client, the printed reviews (which are grabbed from a helper) return correctly, but the metrics (which are grabbed on an onReady callback to the helper) are inaccurate. When the onReady function is run, the current result of the local reviews collection contains the union of the clicked class and the previously clicked class, even though the reviews themselves print correctly.

I've also tried using autoTracker, but I got the same results. Is there a way to clear previous subscribe results before updating them?

publish:

```js
Meteor.publish('reviews', function validReviews(courseId, visiblity) {
    console.log(courseId);
    console.log(visiblity);
    var ret = null
    //show valid reviews for this course
    if (courseId != undefined && courseId != "" && visiblity == 1) {
     console.log("checked reviews for a class");
     ret =  Reviews.find({class : courseId, visible : 1}, {limit: 700});
    } else if (courseId != undefined && courseId != "" && visiblity == 0) { //invalidated reviews for a class
     console.log("unchecked reviews for a class");
     ret =  Reviews.find({class : courseId, visible : 0},  
   {limit: 700});
    } else if (visiblity == 0) { //all invalidated reviews
     console.log("all unchecked reviews");
     ret =  Reviews.find({visible : 0}, {limit: 700});
    } else { //no reviews 
     console.log("no reviews");
     //will always be empty because visible is 0 or 1. allows meteor to still send the ready 
     //flag when a new publication is sent
     ret = Reviews.find({visible : 10}); 
    }
    //console.log(ret.fetch())
    return ret
   });
```

subscribe:

```js
this.helpers({
      reviews() {
        return Reviews.find({});
      }        
    });
```

and subscribe call, in constructor with the helpers:

```js
constructor($scope) {
    $scope.viewModel(this);

    //when a new class is selected, update the reviews that are returned by the database and update the gauges
    this.subscribe('reviews', () => [(this.getReactively('selectedClass'))._id, 1], {
      //callback function, should only run once the reveiws collection updates, BUT ISNT 
      //seems to be combining the previously clicked class's reviews into the collection
      onReady: function() {
        console.log("class is: ", this.selectedClass);
        if (this.isClassSelected == true) { //will later need to check that the side window is open
          //create initial variables
          var countGrade = 0;
          var countDiff = 0;
          var countQual = 0;
          var count = 0;

          //table to translate grades from numerical value
          var gradeTranslation = ["C-", "C", "C+", "B-", "B", "B-", "A-", "A", "A+"];

          //get all current reviews, which will now have only this class's reviews because of the subscribe.
          var allReviews = Reviews.find({});
          console.log(allReviews.fetch()); 
          console.log("len is " + allReviews.fetch().length)
          if (allReviews.fetch().length != 0) {
            console.log("exist")
            allReviews.forEach(function(review) {
              count++;
              countGrade = countGrade + Number(review["grade"]);
              countDiff = countDiff + review["difficulty"];
              countQual = countQual + review["quality"];
            });

            this.qual = (countQual/count).toFixed(1);
            this.diff = (countDiff/count).toFixed(1);
            this.grade = gradeTranslation[Math.floor(countGrade/count) - 1];
          } else {
            console.log("first else");
            this.qual = 0;
            this.diff = 0;
            this.grade = "-";
          }
        } else {
          console.log("second else");
            this.qual = 0;
            this.diff = 0;
            this.grade = "-";
        } 
      } 
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using pub-sub the minimongo database on the client will contain the union of subscriptions unless they are explicitly cleared. For that reason you want to repeat the query that's in the publication on the client side so that you filter and sort the same way. Minimongo is very fast on the client and you typically have much less data there so don't worry about performance.

In your `constructor` you have:

```
var allReviews = Reviews.find({});
```

instead use:

```
var allReviews = Reviews.find(
  {
    class : (this.getReactively('selectedClass'))._id,
    visible : 1
  },
  {limit: 700}
);
```

Another side tip: javascript is [quite clever](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-javascript.html) about *truthy* and *falsy* values.

```
if (courseId != undefined && courseId != "" && visibility == 1)
```

can be simplified to:

```
if (courseId && visibility)
```

assuming you're using `visibility == 1` to denote `true` and `visibility == 0` to denote `false`

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem perfectly!